# Why is this gunicorn, flask, bokeh application not running with 4 workers?

Tags: python, flask, bokeh, gunicorn

I am learning to use gunicorn, flask and bokeh.
I am trying to set up a little example to use a bokeh app with multiuser. I am working on a debian system on an AWS server with a static IP. I used the [example from git](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/blob/2.4.3/examples/howto/server_embed/flask_gunicorn_embed.py) and edited it in the way I think it should work. I got it to run with this command:

```
gunicorn3 -w 1 --bind 0.0.0.0:8000 wsgi:app
```

But when I change the workers to 4 and the binded port from 5006 to 0 (flaskapp.py), I get this error in the browser console:

> :34163/bkapp/autoload.js?bokeh-autoload-element=4755&bokeh-app-path=/bkapp&bokeh-absolute-url=http://35.XXX.XXX.153:34163/bkapp:1          Failed to load resource: net::ERR_CONNECTION_TIMED_OUT

Can someone tell me, why I get this error?

Here is the relevant code:

**flaskapp.py**

```
import asyncio
from threading import Thread

from flask import Flask, render_template
from tornado.httpserver import HTTPServer
from tornado.ioloop import IOLoop

from bokeh.application import Application
from bokeh.application.handlers import FunctionHandler
from bokeh.embed import server_document
from bokeh.layouts import column
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Slider
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.sampledata.sea_surface_temperature import sea_surface_temperature
from bokeh.server.server import BaseServer
from bokeh.server.tornado import BokehTornado
from bokeh.server.util import bind_sockets
from bokeh.themes import Theme

app = Flask(__name__)

def bkapp(doc):
df = sea_surface_temperature.copy()
source = ColumnDataSource(data=df)

    plot = figure(x_axis_type='datetime', y_range=(0, 25), y_axis_label='Temperature (Celsius)',
                  title="Sea Surface Temperature at 43.18, -70.43")
    plot.line('time', 'temperature', source=source)
    
    def callback(attr, old, new):
        if new == 0:
            data = df
        else:
            data = df.rolling(f"{new}D").mean()
        source.data = ColumnDataSource.from_df(data)
    
    slider = Slider(start=0, end=30, value=0, step=1, title="Smoothing by N Days")
    slider.on_change('value', callback)
    
    doc.add_root(column(slider, plot))
    
    doc.theme = Theme(filename="theme.yaml")

# can't use shortcuts here, since we are passing to low level BokehTornado

bkapp = Application(FunctionHandler(bkapp))

# This is so that if this app is run using something like "gunicorn -w 4" then

# each process will listen on its own port

sockets, port = bind_sockets("0.0.0.0", 0)

@app.route('/', methods=\['GET'\])
def bkapp_page():
script = server_document('http://35.XXX.XXX.153:%d/bkapp' % port)
print("app port: %s", port)
return render_template("embed.html", script=script, template="Flask")

def bk_worker():
asyncio.set_event_loop(asyncio.new_event_loop())

    bokeh_tornado = BokehTornado({'/bkapp': bkapp}, extra_websocket_origins=["*"])
    bokeh_http = HTTPServer(bokeh_tornado)
    bokeh_http.add_sockets(sockets)
    
    server = BaseServer(IOLoop.current(), bokeh_tornado, bokeh_http)
    server.start()
    server.io_loop.start()

t = Thread(target=bk_worker)
t.daemon = True
t.start()
```

**wsgi.py**

```
from flaskapp import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
app.run()
```

**embed.html**

```
\<!DOCTYPE html\>
\<html lang="en"\>
\<head\>
\<meta charset="utf-8"\>
{{ bokeh_css }}
{{ bokeh_js }}
\<link rel="stylesheet" href="./static/css/styles.css" type="text/css"/\>
\<link rel="shortcut icon" href="./static/favicon/favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon"\>
\</head\>
\<body\>
\<div class="head"\>
\<a href="http://"\>\<img src="./static/images/logo.png" width="93px" height="36px"/\>\</a\>
\</div\>
\<div class="body"\>
{{ script|safe }}
\</div\>
\</body\>
\</html\>
```

Comment: Well, that what I would expect if you just change the port.

Comment: I changed the port for the bokeh app, because I can not run 4 instances on the same port. The line "bind_sockets("0.0.0.0", 0)" is the one that I changed. I used 5006 when I just had one worker and changed it to 0 for using 4 workers so it takes a random free port for every worker. What exactly do you mean with "just change the port"?